# Derivative of $(Ax - y)^T(Ax - y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are vectors of $n$ dimensions and $A$ is matrix $n\times n$

Tags: calculus, matrices, vectors, matrix-calculus

Derivative of $(Ax - y)^T(Ax - y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are vector of $n$ dimension and $A$ is matrix $n\times n$

I solved the function and broke it down to following expression:

$$f = x^TA^TAx -2x^TA^Ty + y^Ty$$

When taking its derivative $df/dx$ I am applying product rule to first and reaching to.

$$x^TA^TA + A^TAx - 2 A^Ty$$

Now the problem is this answer in not in any of the given options. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension of $x^TA^TA$ and $A^TAx$ don't match.

$$A^TAx + A^TAx-2A^Ty = 2A^TAx - 2A^Ty$$

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you please reply how did you come up with this?
I tried replacing $A^TA$ with B and reached
$x^T(A^TA + A^TA)$ =>
$2x^TA^TA$

Comment: There are two conventions for matrix calculus, rowwise or column wise. I used the column conventions. Hence, I do not end up with $x^TB$ but $Bx$.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the book: [The matrix cookbook](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwirp4-I2vrTAhXLhFQKHd1XD_gQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imm.dtu.dk%2Fpubdb%2Fviews%2Fedoc_download.php%2F3274%2Fpdf%2Fimm3274.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFJbycDGy_rsijRk8x9LE8C1v4Mpw&sig2=RgPrOyvWLYGVPzhdoQFqUw)
[image]

And then apply to your problem:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =& \frac{\partial (x^\top A^\top Ax - x^\top A^\top y - y^\top Ax + y^\top y)}{\partial x}\\
=& A^\top Ax + A^\top Ax - A^\top y- A^\top y\\
=& 2 A^\top Ax - 2A^\top y
\end{align}
And moreover, 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =& -Ax-Ax+2y\\
=& -2Ax + 2y
\end{align}

It is worth to point that, since your function is a $\mathbb{R}^n \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}^1$, which means the result is a real value. Then it could apply the formula. If the result is a vector or matrix, it will become more complicated.